# What does SAS do if you try to read past the end of a record?

Tags: database, sas

With this code, I write lines of 109 characters.

```
DATA _NULL_;
    SET  TP_FREQ_DATA;
    FILE TPFREQ01;
    OUT = MESSAGE_TYPE || ORIG_ADDR_ID || ORIG_SUB_ADDR_ID || EDI_VERSION || PUT(ERROR_DATA,$3.);
    PUT OUT $CHAR109.;
RUN;
```

Next I read it back in, specifying positions further than the 109the character

```
DATA TEST;                   
     INFILE TPFREQ01 LRECL=109 ; 
     INPUT 
         @1    RECTYPE   $CHAR3.    /* RECORD TYPE  */ 
         @04   ROAD      $CHAR8.    /* SENDING ROAD */ 
         @116  VERSION   $CHAR12.   /* EDI VERSION  */ 
         @1947 ERRORS    $CHAR3.    /* ERROR 1      */ 
         ;     
     IF RECTYPE ^= '421' THEN DELETE;                
     IF ERRORS ^= ' ' THEN ERRORS = 'YES';           
       ELSE ERRORS = 'NO';          
RUN;
```

Can anyone help with the value of VERSION and ERRORS because the lengths of one line is 109 but the pointers is at 116 and 1947.

Comment: Are we supposed to know what is in TPFRQDAT?

Comment: it is just a query from database

Comment: Your question is cluttered up with a lot of information that does not matter and did not have a decent introduction. This discourages people from helping you.

Comment: Your lengths are confusing and don't seem to align with your data. Why is the first variable 3 characters? An extra space at the end? What about the last one? Do you need to send a fixed width file, or would a CSV or delimited file work better? If you're after what happens when you read past a line, your question is answered below.

Comment: Is this a real program or are you just trying to create an example where you are reading past the line.  If it is a real problem and you generated the data using fixed length strings you should just read with formatted input rather than using column numbers.

Comment: Thanks all, this is the real project, data migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the default FLOWOVER infile option when you attempt to move past the end of the line with the pointer control you will instead move to the start of the next line.  So `@116 VERSION $CHAR12.` will read the first 12 characters of the second line and `@1947 ERRORS $CHAR3.` will read the first three characters of the third line.

You can see this in action by using the COLUMN= option on the INFILE statement.

```
data test;
 infile cards column=cc ;
 put 'START ' cc= ;
 input @1 v1 $char3. @ ;
 put v1= cc= _infile_;
 input @200  v2 $char3. @;
 put v2= cc= _infile_;
 input @100 v3 $char3. @;
 put v3= cc= _infile_;
cards;
1234567890
ABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQRST
;
```

Results:

```
START cc=1
v1=123 cc=4 1234567890
v2=ABC cc=4 ABCDEFGHIJ
v3=KLM cc=4 KLMNOPQRST
START cc=4
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, if I have had seen this post earlier in 2020, I wouldn't have much trouble in my old project.

Answer (score 2):

What SAS does when reading past the end of the line depends on the `xxxxOVER` option on the [infile](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=n1rill4udj0tfun1fvce3j401plo.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) (or filename) statement.

The default is `flowover`, which tells SAS: when you reach the end of the line, if there is a request past that, treat the next line as starting at (line end position + 1).  This is the default because of card-column data back in the day, you'd have 4 rows or whatever of data, each 80 columns long, to put out 320 total columns; and while you could use `#1` etc. to read the cards, you also could just treat it as one "big" line of 320.

As Tom correctly notes, this behavior is a bit different than what you might assume.  When it flows over, it then treats the next line as starting `@1` but instead of going to `lrecl+1` in your input, it actually goes to the next input field that is higher than `lrecl` - so in this case, `version` is read from column 1, and column 116 becomes the new column one.  The same thing happens with `ERRORS`; they're read from the third row, with column 1947 becoming the new column one.  Each three sets of rows are read in a group like this.

When it reaches EOF, if it notices it hasn't read in the last full line, and so writes `LOST CARD` to the log, and discards the entire last row of data (as it's incomplete).

If this isn't what you want, then you have some options.

`MISSOVER` says to make any value that includes any distance past the end of line as missing.  So, for example, if you read `input @105 willbemissed $10.` here, that is partially in the valid area and partly after end of line, so the `willbemissed` variable will be set to missing, even if 105-109 had some nonmissing data in them.  Anything entirely after 109 also is set to missing, and then the next input statement starts afresh at position 1 on the next line.

`TRUNCOVER` says to work like `MISSOVER`, except don't throw away that partial data - keep it.  This is the most common one I see today.

There is also `STOPOVER`, which says to throw an error if it tries to read past end of line.

Finally, there is another option pair: `LRECL` and `PAD`.  You could set `LRECL=2000` and `PAD`, and then SAS would pretend all lines are 2000 long, whether or not they are actually that long - and so your read in would work fine.  It wouldn't find anything there of course, but it would just read one line per row as normal (as long as you didn't go past 2000, anyway).

Comment: Thanks Joe, actually I just found out the answer, it is nearly the same as you said.
When the line pointer is out of range, it will automatically select the firt available value in the next line.
Therefore, version will be the first value in second line and error will be the first value in third line.
This is SAS systax, I search google a lot and found out this answer in one documentation

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Joe, actually I just found out the answer, it is nearly the same as you said. When the line pointer is out of range, it will automatically select the firt available value in the next line. Therefore, version will be the first value in second line and error will be the first value in third line. This is SAS systax, I search google a lot and found out this answer in one documentation

Comment: That’s incorrect. You aren’t reading in a way that would read field by field - you’re using positional input. Put the code above in SAS; it will not do what you suggest. Given enough rows it would eventually read in something for ERROR but it would be about nineteen rows down (1947/109).

Comment: @joe You are wrong.  With FLOWOVER when you try to read past the end it reads from the beginning of the next line even with pointer motion.  Basically the @ XXX is translated to @ 1 of next line.

Comment: @Tom You misunderstand me. Read my answer - that’s nearly verbatim from it. However OP here suggests that the code in the question would read the error from the third line - it’s more like the nineteenth line.

Comment: The code in the question will read two values from first line, assuming there are values, then third value from second line and then fourth vlaue from third line.

Comment: Hmm... you're right.  I hadn't paid attention to the deleting code in the example, and thought the zero records were consistent with my understanding.  I find that choice particularly odd on SAS's part!